# Color code for rows by following cell color

Tags: vba, excel

I just wonder if it is possible by using VBA code to fill row with color based on a colored cell.

For example

[image]

I want Row 4 to be the same color as B4. I am using the following codes but it just won't work. I guess I need to do something else, do advise.

```
Sub Color1()

Dim lastR as Long, i as Long

lastR = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastR To 2 Step -1

If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B") = Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
 Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End if

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: you want row 4, column D or D4 to match the color of B4?

Comment: @The_Barman Apologize for the wrong info, it should be Row 4 matching color with B4. I will make the amendments now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should do it (added WITH for sheet1):

```
Sub Color1()

Dim lastR As Long, i As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastR To 2 Step -1

        If .Cells(i, "B").Interior.Pattern = xlNone Then
            .Rows(i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            .Rows(i).Interior.Color = .Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color
        End If

    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply.. unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Comment: you have data in column A? as without it you will get no rows to update. (as lastR is using column A) Put something in A13 or change to B and it should work.

Comment: I see.. No wonder.. It works fine now! Thanks! btw have a happy new year!

Comment: Indeed, have a good new year too (though if you are working I hope it is not all work work work). :)